# Is there a way to specify a configuration file when launching the Tor Browser Bundle?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux, configuration

I start Tor using the Firefox binary inside the bundle and it seems to work. How do I make it point to a custom torrc file and not the file inside the bundle? I'd like to do something like this:

```
firefox -f /custom/torrc
```

Comment: This question might have an answer for you: http://tor.stackexchange.com/q/1065/88

Comment: You can't give Firefox a `torrc`. You would need to change it like in the answer above.

Comment: @JensKubieziel Actually, the answer to http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/what-happened-to-torrc-in-tor-browser-bundle seems wrong. The primary configuration file is now /Data/Tor/torrc-defaults, right? I'm going to add a new answer there.