# Install a Tor relay on Windows with Tor Browser Bundle

Tags: relays, configuration, windows

I can not install or configure a Tor relay.
I had Tor downloaded, installed several times on Windows XP.
There is no Vidalia in it or came with it.
The union button gives me no options like Vidalia used to do.

Answer (score 1):

The Tor Browser Bundle which you is downloaded by default is configured as a client only. When you want to use it as a relay you can either [edit the `torrc`](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/1072/88) or [download a relay bundle](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en). For the latter case there is a package which is configured as non-exit relay and one which is an exit.

Comment: as far as I can tell you can not run a relay if you are running windows which is a shame as that is what I want to do aswell as Johnny BeGood
The [download a relay bundle](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en) link you provided by Jens Kubieziel♦ above dose not lead to anywhere to download a relay bundle?