# How to modify the Tor Browser window for Tor Browser Bundle v.3.6.2

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox, configuration

With reference to this question: [What happened to torrc in Tor Browser Bundle?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/what-happened-to-torrc-in-tor-browser-bundle)
, I wish to add a button/an option to the Tor Firefox Browser Window  where users can automatically input which country nodes they do not want to use:

[image: Tor Firefox Browser Window]

This will of course use the ExcludeNode command (for example:)`ExcludeNodes {al},{dz},{ao}`and link with the torrc configuration file (path: /Applications/TorBrowser.app/Data/Tor/torrc) -- my objective is so that users do not have to edit the torrc configuration file themselves. What is the best way to approach this?