# How to edit the torrc to run a hidden service in tails?

Tags: configuration, tails

Where to find a `torrc` file for configuring a hidden service within tails? I mean I cannot see the `torrc` file with the following lines like this:

```
"# this section is for hidden services#"
```

Comment: What operating system are you using? If you are GNU/Linux, for example an Ubunut server, the file is `/etc/tor/torrc`.

Comment: Does this question help you: https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/1065/88

Comment: @LutzHorn I am using tails

Comment: Do you want to use Tails to run a hidden service?

Comment: @LutzHorn yes and also on my windows 7 OS the torc file is different than the one described for hidden service configuration on torproject.org .I cannot find the lines for Hidden service configuartion in that torc file.

Comment: Please don't mix configuration questions for Tails an Windows 7. If you have a question about configuring a hidden service on Windows 7, please create a new question.

Comment: @LutzHorn ok but still i havent got an answer about finding and siting a torc file so first i can run it on a local server (XAMPP) for testing purposes.Tell me how to find it on tails?

Answer (score 2):

From a ticket:

> running a hiddenservice from Tails is not (yetç in our design goals.

https://labs.riseup.net/code/issues/6601

Answer (score 0):

The torrc file is in `/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc`. You can add a hidden service with lines like these:

```
TORRC=/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc
echo HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service >> $TORRC
echo HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80 >> $TORRC
```

You also have to allow connections to it in iptables:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m owner --uid-owner debian-tor -j ACCEPT
```

Adding this feature to Tails is currently a work in progress, see [this ticket](https://labs.riseup.net/code/issues/7879) for more information.